# Stratonovich SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

> Suppose $u$ satisfies the problem: $$ du= \nabla u \circ \,dW(t) +|\nabla u|\,dt$$
> I want to prove that $ v(x,t):= u(x+W(t),t)$ satisfies the PDE $\partial_tv=|\nabla v|$. Here '$\circ$' denotes the Stratonovich differential and $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T)$.

Applying the chain rule in Stratonovich sense we get, $$d(u(x+W(t),t))= \nabla u (x+W(t),t)\circ dW(t) + \partial_t u(x+W(t),t)\,dt \implies d(u(x+W(t),t))-\nabla u (x-W(t),t)\circ dW(t)= \partial_t u(x+W(t),t)\,dt.$$
This gives $|\nabla v| = \partial_t v$.
Are these computations correct? If we specify the initial data $u(t,0)=u_0$, can it be said that $u_0(x+W(t))$ solves  $|\nabla v| = \partial_t v$?

Comment: You are making an ansatz and find the equation $|\nabla u|=\partial_t u$ that $u(x,t)$ must solve (I don't see the need to introduce $v(x,t)$). Can you solve $|\nabla u|=\partial_t u$ ?

Comment: Hello, I am just trying to make a change of variable and convert the stochastic PDE into deterministic PDE with random input so that it boils down to studying the properties of deterministic PDE. I don't know how to solve $\partial_t u = |\nabla u|$.

Comment: As far as I can see the solvabiliy of the stochastic PDE is equivalent to the solvability of that deterministic PDE. In other words: without the latter the whole thing "exists" only in the vacuum.

Comment: Yes you are right, please consider saying something about my two questions.

Comment: 1. The computations are correct. 2. The second question I don't understand. $u$ is a function of $t\in[0,\infty)$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. What do you mean by $u(t,0)=u_0$ ? Even if $u_0$ is a smooth function of $x\in\mathbb R$ it is certainly not true that $u_0(x+W(t))$ solves an equation where you can take a partial $t$ derivative because - as we know $W(t)$ is not differentiable. You should rethink that whole question before you can expect better answers.

Comment: You are correct we cannot differentiate in the time variable, I think it will solve $du = \nabla u \circ \,dW(t)$ instead.